# RVMSUDO - not responding to command, hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I just installed a fresh rackspace Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VPS server.

I am following the guide here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Everything is going great, until I enter:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

My terminal hangs and nothing happens, unless I cntrl-C.

Some info:

```
rvm 1.16.20 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]


ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]


rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: try after `rvm get stable`, maybe it is because of https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/da3989566a1ddd7a2a690cb9792cf309756823c9

Comment: Yup, that did it.  Was making me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1312

Update RVM again:

```
rvm get head
```